# Nginx can't handle .br (Brotli) and .gz (GZip) file requests properly

Tags: nginx, gzip

I can't set up nginx 1.18 (Ubuntu 22.04 as a server env, Chrome 104 as a client) for dealing with `.br` or `.gz` files.

My frontend code bundler (Parcel 2) has generated `.br` and `.gz` index.html files but when I'm trying to access https://mysite/index.html it throws `404 Not found`, and with https://mysite/index.html.br it's just trying to download `Brotli` file.

My assumption is that Nginx should send `.br` or `.gz` file to Chrome and Chrome ***should automatically extract it*** to regular html-file and display web page. Is it right or not?

This is an extract from my `nginx.conf`:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;
...
...
...
       ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        brotli on;
        brotli_static on;
        brotli_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        text/x-component
        application/xml
        application/xml+rss
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/atom+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-font-opentype
        application/x-font-truetype
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/octet-stream
        font/opentype
        font/truetype
        font/eot
        font/otf
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        image/vnd.microsoft.icon
        image/bmp;
```

This is server conf:

```
...
    location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|jpg|jpeg|git|ico|css|eot|woff|woff2|svg|webmanifest)$ {
      root /var/www/main;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /webgl$uri =404;
    }

    location / {
      root /var/www/main/webgl;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
...
```

What I have to do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the uncompressed version on your server, you need to use [nginx gunzip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html) to make nginx uncompress the file when client requests the uncompressed version of the file.

`gzip_static` only tells nginx to send the `.gz` version to clients who tell they accept gzip encoded responses.

Comment: Thank you Tero! I see that Chrome initiates request *with* support of br and gz formats: "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br". But I'm still getting error like "403 Forbidden" due to nginx can't browse root directory because it's impossible to find index.html (just index.html.br and index.html.gz exist)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Nginx can't handle `index.html.br` and `index.html.gz` without having `index.html` version in folder.

**Solution**: Just add files without compression to your folder and Nginx will send compressed files
(of course if browser will send proper `accept-encoding` attribute in request (e.g. `accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br`).

Ref https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1367